# Проблема автоматического отключение от сервера

Tags: python, python-2.7

Никак не могу отключиться от сервера автоматический спустя определнное время

```
import getpass
import datetime

endTime = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
date = datetime.datetime.now()
dateName = str(date.day) + "." + str(date.month) + "." + str(date.year) + " " + str(date.hour) + " " + str(date.minute)

login = raw_input("Login: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
session = open('localhost').with(UsernameAndPassword(login,password))
command = 'list'
get_terminal = session.get_terminal()
response = terminal.execute(command)
if str(response.http_example()) == '200':
    print("successful connections")
while True:
    com = raw_input("Command: ")
    if(com == ''):
        break
    if(com == "exit"):
        break
    else:
        command = com
        get_terminal = session.get_terminal()
        response = terminal.execute(command)

        f= open(dateName + ".txt","a",)
        for line in response.output():
            print(line)
            f.write(line + " \n")
        f.close()
else:
    print("404" + str(response.http_example()))
close(session)
```

Comment: Что это значит: `session = open('localhost').with(UsernameAndPassword(login,password))` ?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica подключение к серверу, я просто скрыл функций

Comment: Добавьте код подключения к серверу . А то сбивает с толку, да и для ответа код подключения к серверу нужен.